# map the dictionary and list of dictionary,finally update the list of dictionary after mapping

Tags: python, dictionary

```
req_dict =  {
1: {'f1': 'name', 'f2': 'age', 'f3': 'class'}, 
2: {'f1': 'company', 'f2': 'salary', 'f3': 'age', 'f4': 'class'}, 
3: {'f1': 'Feature', 'f2': 'sum', 'f3': 'diff', 'f4': 'multiply', 'f5': 'div'}
}

level_input =  [
{3: {'sum': 'NONE', 'diff': 'yes', 'multiply': 'NONE', 'div': 'NONE', 'FEATURE': 'Maths'}}, 
{2: {'COMPANY': 'NONE', 'SALARY': 'Pass', 'AGE': 'NONE', 'CLASS': 'unknown'}},
{1: {'NAME': 'Pass', 'AGE': 'NONE', 'CLASS': '3'}}
]
```

i need output as

```
updated_level_input = [
{3: {'f1': 'Maths', 'f2': 'none', 'f3': 'yes', 'f4': 'NONE', 'f5': 'NONE'}}, 
{2: {'f1': 'NONE', 'f2': 'Pass', 'f3': 'NONE', 'f4': 'unknown'}}, 
{1: {'f1': 'Pass', 'f2': 'NONE', 'f3': '3'}}
]
```

i tried below code

```
level_dict = {}
    [level_dict.update(key) for key in levels_input]

    for key in req_dict:
        #print key
        for dict_key in req_dict[key]:
            print dict_key          
            searchKey = req_dict[key][dict_key]
            print searchKey.upper()         
            if searchKey.upper() in level_dict[key].keys():
                #print level_dict[key].keys()
                req_dict[key][dict_key] = req_dict[key][searchKey.upper()]                  
            else:
                req_dict[key][dict_key] = level_dict[key][searchKey]
print [req_dict]
```

but i get the output as

```
updated_level_input=[
{3: {'f1': 'Maths', 'f2': 'none', 'f3': 'yes', 'f4': 'NONE', 'f5': 'NONE'}, 
2: {'f1': 'NONE', 'f2': 'Pass', 'f3': 'NONE', 'f4': 'unknown'}, 
1: {'f1': 'Pass', 'f2': 'NONE', 'f3': '3'}}
]
```

basically i tried to modify `req_dict` input,which is not `correct.i` should modify `level_input` list

Comment: Can you explain what's the expected result?

Comment: i must modify the original list(level_input) by mapping each keys of dictionary in the value field with each value of dictionary for respective keys in both list and dictionary(inputs).if there is a match (ex:sum=sum,diff=diff) then update the list  key with dictionary key like       [
{3: {'f1': 'Maths', 'f2': 'none', 'f3': 'yes', 'f4': 'NONE', 'f5': 'NONE'}}, 
{2: {'f1': 'NONE', 'f2': 'Pass', 'f3': 'NONE', 'f4': 'unknown'}}, 
{1: {'f1': 'Pass', 'f2': 'NONE', 'f3': '3'}}

Comment: i must modify the original list(level_input) by mapping each keys of dictionary in the value field with each value of dictionary in a dictionary(req_dict) for respective keys in both list and dictionary(inputs).if there is a match (ex:sum in level_input =sum in re_dict,diff in leve_input =diff in req_input ) then update the list  key with dictionary key like       [
{3: {'f1': 'Maths', 'f2': 'none', 'f3': 'yes', 'f4': 'NONE', 'f5': 'NONE'}}, 
{2: {'f1': 'NONE', 'f2': 'Pass', 'f3': 'NONE', 'f4': 'unknown'}}, 
{1: {'f1': 'Pass', 'f2': 'NONE', 'f3': '3'}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code did not break up req_dict and thus the last print statement just prints out a list of one dictionary which is the req_dict.  Try to replace the last print statement with the following:

```
print [{key: value} for key, value in req_dict.iteritems()]
```